# In Typescript is it possible to peg a generic type parameter to a constrained generic type parameter from an indexed access type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Let's say I have the interface `Foo` with a generic of `T` that extends `Bar`:

```js
interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
  a: ...,
  b: ...,
  c: ...,
}
```

And I want a new interface that uses a subset of Foo

```js
interface MyType<U> {
  a: Foo<U>['a'],
  c: Foo<U>['c'],
}
```

Is there a way to peg the generic parameter of my new type `MyType` to the constrained generic parameter of `Foo` with a [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) or something? My IDE would let me know that `MyType`'s generic type, `U`, needs to extend `Bar` but *I'd like to know if there's a way that doesn't depend on correction raised by the IDE say, if the original type, `Foo`'s, generic constraint changes.*

This would work but, again, has to be corrected if the generic constraint changes:

```js
interface MyType<U extends Bar> {
  a: Foo<U>['a'],
  c: Foo<U>['c'],
}
```

Comment: On a sidenote, why not `type MyType<U extends Bar> = Pick<Foo<U>, "a" | "c">;`? Doesn't solve the problem but does solve the redundancy involved.

Comment: No I don't think this is possible, but it would be nice for some specific use cases.

Comment: You're right! It could totally use `Pick` instead~. Wasn't mentioned in the o.g. bc of relevance but the specific use case I have in mind uses nested indexing on a type and I wasn't able to get `Pick` to work with that.

Comment: Try this: `type MyType<U> = U extends Foo<any> ? { ... } : never;` -- it produces usable type only if `U` extends any flavor of `Foo`. You can change left side to `type MyType<U extends Foo<any>>` to get better TS error messages (like "Type 'X' does not satisfy the constraint 'Foo<any>'"). Also, in the right part you can use `infer T` instead of `any` if you need it in field definitions.